# Where is source code for Wacom Tablet settings page in Gnome settings?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I am trying to locate the source code for this settings page. I want to build an annotation program using this implementation because it is very smooth.

[image: Wacom Tablet settings on Gnome 3]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is in https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/tree/master/panels/wacom and possibly https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/master/plugins/wacom too.

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/blob/master/panels/wacom/gnome-wacom-panel.desktop.in.in has a `gnome-control-center wacom` EXEC and sure enough running that launches that settings panel!

Comment: Simple and smooth implementation, I love it! Didn't know it was there there. Note that the actual drawing area logic is located in `cc-drawing-area.c` and takes mere 200 lines.

Comment: Super appreciate the further guidance, I don't know much about C programming yet and it would have taken me a while to figure that out that it was in cc-drawing-area.c, although that makes sense now that you mention it. Still wondering where all those other parts are used.

Comment: Happy that helped! Just to clarify how I found it, I simply looked up where in the source code the test button's text was assigned (`"Test Your _Settings"`) and followed the use/definition chain (`cc_wacom_panel_constructed()`=> `cc_drawing_area_new()` => `CC_TYPE_DRAWING_AREA` and finally the `G_DEFINE_TYPE` macro in `cc-drawing-area.c`). It's very simple, though OOP done in C can be a bit confusing at first.

Comment: Thanks, how did you know to put a _ in front of the settings?

Comment: It's a way to specify the hotkey for a button, you'll see on the screen it if you hold `Alt`. Github's search is fuzzy so it should find it either way, locally you could find it with something like `git grep -Ei "test\W+your" *.c` or a fuzzy search tool like `agrep` without knowing it was there.